# What is the answer to this test question?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

[image]

[Here's the link](http://nouryoku-up.blogspot.jp/2016/06/iq-test-no.002.html)

What is the answer to this test question?

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be

> H

The top row is a simple arithmetic series. The bottom row starts with the middle entry of the top row.

> the bottom row then continues with its middle entry being 3/4 of the first entry, and the third entry being 4/5 of the middle entry.
>  so 4/5 of 30 is 24.

Comment: As reinforcement for this solution, it produces a situation where the sums of each of the top two rows are double the sums of each of the bottom two rows